# load particular .icns size

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

In my cocoa app, how can I load/scale my .icns file?  In this case, I want to load up my 16x16 image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load it as an `NSImage` (`+imageNamed:`), grab one of its `NSImageRep`s (`-representations`), then call `setSize:NSMakeSize(16,16)` on it.

Answer (score 2):

With 'file' being a NSString with the icns file path, use this to load the image:

```
NSImage* img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file]
```

Then, the NSImage 'img' will contain the icns image. To resize it to 16x16, use this:

```
[img setSize: NSMakeSize(16,16)];
```